# wget download a file using secure connection

Tags: bash, wget

I want to massively download video files from amazon using wget. The code I've being using for a single file:

```
wget \
--no-check-certificate \ 
--no-proxy \
--post-data "AWSAccessKeyId=XXX&Expires=XXX&Signature=XXX" \
https://XXX.s3.amazonaws.com/MyIntroVideo.mp4
```

And I get `ERROR 403: Forbidden.` But if I simply go to the browser and paste the following url

`https://XXX.s3.amazonaws.com/MyIntroVideo.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=XXX&Expires=XXX&Signature=XXX`

I can view and download the video. What I'm doing wrong with wget and why I'm getting forbidden access error ( what is different from simply going to this url in browser )?

**UPDATE:** The first thing I tried was passing parameters with same url:

```
wget \
--no-check-certificate \ 
--no-proxy \
https://XXX.s3.amazonaws.com/MyIntroVideo.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=XXX&Expires=XXX&Signature=XXX
```

But it didn't work either.

Comment: Why are you using `--post-data`?  That is converting a GET request to a POST request under-the-covers.  Your browser request is a GET.

Comment: @Joe I'm getting the same error, it was the first thing I tried. Code was `wget --no-check-certificate url`

Answer (score 3):

Put the URL in single quotes:

```
wget \
--no-check-certificate \ 
--no-proxy \
'https://XXX.s3.amazonaws.com/MyIntroVideo.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=XXX&Expires=XXX&Signature=XXX'
```

Otherwise the ampersands between query parameters may be interpreted by the shell as separators between commands and therefore wget only sees up to the `AWSAccessKeyId=XXX` and no signature.

Alternatively an easier approach may be to use a dedicated S3 client tool such as [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd).